# user elasticsearch index commands with heroku bonsai

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, elasticsearch, tire

I'm trying to use the command on bonsai but it did not work, some get the same problem? thank's

```
curl -XDELETE 'http://[your tire]all/_query' -d '{
"ids" : {
"values" : ["35" ,"34", "33", "32", "31", "29"]
}
}'
```

Comment: What happened? What's the actual url you used?

Comment: thank's Frederick for your interest

well i get on the logs this: ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find User with id=1)

Comment: and i'm trying to delete this user from the tire using the curl -xdelete command

Comment: i'm using that https://xxxxxxxxxx-3455.us-east-1.bonsai.io etc url

Comment: The two seem rather unrelated - you'll not get an ActiveRecord error by running curl against elasticsearch.

Comment: why not? the problem seems on the elasticsearch index

Comment: A curl command like that doesn't touch rails at all, so how could it?

Comment: well, but why this command is on elasticsearch api to use?